# Issue with Production Build created using Expo

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native, expo, react-native-ios

We recently launched our production app, built using expo. Some of our iPhone users are noticing as issue with auto upgrade of the app.
When the users upgrade from the previous version to the new version and log in, they see a black bar on the top and bottom of the screen (image attached).

This issue however disappears when the user reinstalls the app.

We have noticed this on iphone 7 plus and iphone X phones running iOS 12.1.

The current version of the app (built using expo) uses expo version: “^30.0.0”.

The previous version of the app (developed with angular 1), was built using XCode 7.3.1

[image]